# Apple rejects app due to third party REST API needs location?

Tags: ios, iphone, location, app-store

I'm using a REST API for getting currency exchange rates, and it works very well. The problem I ran into is that Apple rejects my app due to missing purpose string regards location from third party API.

The API I use is the following:
https://github.com/exchangeratesapi/exchangeratesapi, and I can't find anything about accessing sensitive data such as location, and therefore I wonder what I am missing?

Also, since I do not find anything about accessing location data, what should I write in the purpose string?

Best regards,
Rusben

Comment: I guess this is good for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52002466/error-appstore-connect-missing-purpose-string-in-info-plist-file

Comment: @RezaDehnavi Thank you I look into it.

Comment: @RezaDehnavi Sorry, that's not the problem. I DO NOT need location from user for my app purpose. The problem is Apple THINK I need the location, but that's not the case. What I do not know is wheter this is mandatory since I do use third party API. Do you have any suggestion on that?

Comment: OK, I got it, let me create a project same you and check it.

Comment: Are you 100% sure this is the library that they’re talking about? When they say you have some third party API that is using location services without stating the purpose in your plist, they don’t necessarily mean this web API. It could be any framework that you’ve included in your project. Or did they explicitly say that this exchange rate API was the source of the problem? Usually its analytics/ad frameworks that cause this problem. Perhaps include the relevant text of Apple’s rejection in your question...

Comment: Hi @RusbenWladiskoz, Is this a ReactNative app by any chance? If it is, this might be related to this issue on Github: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20879, if you're working with a version before 0.6.

Comment: Just test your application with module which using that third party API. I was pretending that you are using exchange rates API and my be it was using user location to give related data for first. While running application in  Module using that API look at the status bar that navigation icon is appearing or not. so that you will get clarity wether that module using location data or not.

Comment: You keep insisting this is related to this exchange rate web service. That almost certainly is not the API they’re talking about. It probably has something to do with some other framework that you have linked, e.g. AdMob https://stackoverflow.com/a/56778958/1271826. So, what frameworks are you using?